# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'checkDomStatus' of undefine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this error message from mobile device on my React app, but I could not track down the issue.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'checkDomStatus' of undefine

Could anyone help me to understand what this error means?
Is this a critical error?

Comment: it mean that  it try to find function checkDomStatus but not able to get it, it is no where to found

Comment: remember these kinds of messages are  symptoms. not the real problem. the real problem might be somewhere else entirely and might a small problem like some object is null. so debug your code.and what actually causes reactjs to give this error.

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your code so we can help.

Comment: Perhaps what some people are missing in the context of this issue is that `checkDomStatus` is not a function or property on an object anywhere in the source code of the application, therefore it's unknown where this error is originating from.  I too am seeing this error in my application.  My guess is that it's coming from a 3rd party library or browser extension/plugin.  I'm seeing it on multiple different pages of my app as well as different browsers and platforms.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. It appears to be happening in Chrome on Android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to occur when user using NAVER higgs browser.

Someone reported in NAVER Developer forum, but nobody answer it.

https://developers.naver.com/forum/posts/21372

Comment: The link itself is not considered a good answer. Please expand.

Comment: You misunderstood. The link is good. The answer containing just a link in not considered a good answer by SO. Link can go broken. Then the answer has no value.

Comment: I understood your comment. But, my intention is giving notice about even origin development forum cannot respond to this question.

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer where it doesn't actually answer the question.  It provides a small amount of information, in that it shows the question has been asked elsewhere, but since there's no answer available there either this isn't answering anything.